# How to draw a desired path on grid with letters on desired coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image]

I know how to draw grid as the above figure. But don't know how to position A(0, 0), (x, 0), B(x, y), (0, y) at (0, 0), (5, 0), (5, 4), (0, r) respectively.

I know how to draw a connected rectangles, but don't know how to draw a distinguishable path on the grid as the above picture. Does anybody know how to make the above picture?

When I try rectangles to make some similar path in the below code it doesn't appear.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[step=1cm, color=gray] (0, 0) grid (5, 4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the four angles are concerned, I'd use a `\foreach` with some simple code for positioning. Technically, you could just write four node commands, it depends on the situation and personal taste.

For the path, just use a `\draw` command with coordinates. These are the coordinates:

[image]

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[step=1cm, color=gray] (0, 0) grid (5, 4);

\foreach \coord/\label [count=\xi] in {
    {0,0}/{$A(0, 0)$},
    {5,4}/{$B(x, y)$},
    {5,0}/{$(x, 0)$},
    {0,4}/{$(0, y)$}
}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\anch{mod(\xi,2) ? "north" : "south"}
    \node[anchor=\anch] at (\coord) {\label};
}

\draw[line width=3pt, rounded corners] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (3,1) -- (3,2) -- (5,2) -- (5,4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code is really helpful. I'm really a beginner as to using Texworks. When I opened some readme files of Miktex and Tikz, there were some conditions about license and copyright so I depended on this website to learn how to draw some graphs and diagrams. Do you know some other websites for a drawing tutorial?  https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-1/tb88mertz.pdf

Comment: @buzzee Tutorial for Tikz?

Comment: Yes. Yes! The more comprehensive the tutorial, the better.

Comment: @buzzee Never had to use a tutorial to be honest. I learned using this site, first asking some questions, then answering. :D

Comment: @buzzee You already have a good tutorial in your system. Open a terminal window and type command `texdoc pgfmanual` and start reading from page 28. An alternative could be reading from [`texdoc.net`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf#page=28)

Comment: @Ignasi Oh didn't know about that. Good to know!

Comment: @Alenanno Glad to help you. All packages documentation is automatically installed in TeX systems and `texdoc` is the command to open it. In MikTeX i've to type `texdoc --view doc-name`.